# JQuery DataTables - AJAX loading data, processing window won't disappear

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

So I am using the JQuery DataTables plugin, and have configured it to use AJAX to get the data. It works great! However, oddly enough, when accessing a table that contains only 360 records, it gives me this white dialog window at the top of the table that says 'Processing...'. But I am immediately able to jump to the very last page of the records and see them without an issue. However, the processing window wont disappear! Any idea how to close it?

Can't find anything in the documentation about it.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: For starters, use Firebug to make sure the Ajax response is actually completing and returning a success status code.

Comment: I have Firebug, but can't tell if the Ajax response is succesful or not. I don't see any obvious 'failed' on there, but where would I look? All I see in the response tab is the array that contains all the records data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to display the Processing message at all times, you could set the property "bProcessing : false" while declaring the datatable.

Comment: that does work. but i am still curious why it won't disappear. makes me believe something isnt working right, even though it seems to be ok.

Comment: Have you tried this in other browsers? Maybe it is related to MAcOS or FF on Mac. If you are sure that there are no JS error and if you can successfully navigate to other pages when you click on the pagination links then it is probably datatables bug.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are returning the same `sEcho` value in your JSON response, that DataTables sent with the AJAX call.

Comment: Thank you, paging do not work at all, if 'sEcho' param was not iterated properly